# gradle commandLine erro "Cause: error=2, No such file or directory"

Tags: git, gradle, fedora

fedora 33, git install at `/usr/bin/git`, and it is added in `PATH`.

In build.gradle file, I have extract the git hash to use it later on in building the docker image tag.

```
def dockerImageVersion = { ->
  def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  exec {
    commandLine "git describe --first-parent --abbrev=10 --long --dirty"
    standardOutput = stdout
  }
  return stdout.toString().trim()
}

jib {
  from {
    image = 'adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:ubi-minimal-jre'
  }
  to {
    image = "napa/activity-service"
    tags = ["${dockerImageVersion}", "latest"]
  }
  container {
    mainClass = "com.regrexx.user.events.InteractionEventsSinkVerticle"
    jvmFlags = ["-noverify", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"]
    user = "nobody:nobody"
  }
}
```

It gives error: `Cause: error=2, No such file or directory`

Even after I changed the command to be something `commandLine 'echo hello'`, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`commandLine` [is expecting a `List<String>`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:commandLine) and not a whitespaced separated String.

In other words, Gradle is looking for a file in your PATH matching the whole string. It is not parsing the spaces to separate the command and arguments.  It is expecting that to be done already.

Try:

```
commandLine "git", "describe", "--first-parent", "--abbrev=10", "--long", "--dirty"
```